# Не работает директива Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, visual-studio

[image: ошибка в 4 и 48 строчках]
Для InputOnlineFile нужна директива Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles, но Visual Studio ругается на эту директиву, как сделать чтобы директива заработала?

Answer (score 0):

Ты уже используешь Telegram.Bot.Types

.InputOnlineFiles не нужен, так как он член Telegram.Bot.Types

Comment: Как тогда заменить .InputOnlineFiles чтобы бот обратно отправлял отредактированный документ?